# NonConstantMemoryUsage Exception

Tags: java, caliper

**I was doing tests with MeasureMemory turned on and was getting "NonConstantMemoryUsage" exception.**

I did not modify reps as suggested by error message. What am I missing?

```
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes  
[caliper] allocating char array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 34 elements with size 88 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 16 elements with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 70 elements with size 160 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 142 elements with size 304 bytes 
[caliper] allocating char array with 74 elements with size 168 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/String with size 32 bytes

[caliper] allocating org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractReferenceMap$WeakRef with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractReferenceMap$ReferenceEntry with size 32 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 0 elements with size 16 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/joda/time/DateTime with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/hibernate/util/IdentityMap$IdentityKey with size 16 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/hibernate/event/LoadEvent with size 40 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/hibernate/engine/EntityKey with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/hibernate/event/LoadEvent with size 40 bytes 
[caliper] allocating org/hibernate/engine/EntityKey with size 48 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] allocating java/lang/Object array with 1 elements with size 24 bytes 
[caliper] ...more allocations... 
[caliper] [done measured section] 
[caliper] 482 instance(s) allocated per rep 
[caliper] 0 out of thread instance(s) allocated in 1 reps 
[caliper] [starting measured section] 
[caliper] see first run for list of allocations 
[caliper] [done measured section] 
[caliper] 2966 instance(s) allocated per rep 
[caliper] 0 out of thread instance(s) allocated in 2 reps
```

**Error: Not all reps of the inner loop allocate the same number of times! The reps loop should use a constant number of allocations. Are you using the value of reps inside the loop?**

For now I commented the code in AllocationMeasurer which was throwing NonConstantMemoryUsage (Not sure if it's good idea!) so that I could continue further. I am now getting negative bytes allocation.

```
0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=GetCompleteUserInfoByEmail, length=1, trials=5, memory=-Xmx1024M} 5017892000.00 ns; σ=18238565.40 ns @ 3 trials, allocated -45356 instances for a total of -2873264B
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=GetUserByEmail, length=10, trials=5, memory=-Xmx1024M} 5044517000.00 ns; σ=25651666.81 ns @ 3 trials, allocated -45816 instances for a total of -2873264B
```

`length     instances        B        s         linear runtime 

  1              -45356.000  -2873264.000 5.02 ============================= 

  10          -45816.000 -2873264.000 5.04 ==============================`

vm: java 
trial: 0 
benchmark: GetCompleteUserInfoByEmail 
trials: 5 
memory: -Xmx1024M

Comment: You are repeating some function to measure its parameters accurately, and it is doing something different each time it runs. This makes the attempt to make an accurate measurement fail.

Comment: Did check one more time. I was measuring a read operation from db and it's same data set that is returned back.

Comment: Try skipping the first read. It may allocate extra or put some things in cache.

Comment: @ndchandar: Why are you using Caliper to benchmark a *database* operation?  Caliper is designed for *micro*-benchmarks (at the scale of a unit test) not benchmarks at the scale of integration tests.